# Attaching onprogress listener to XMLHttpRequest.upload stops POST data from being sent (wtf?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, upload, xmlhttprequest

## What's this crap?

This code here sends the data through the POST request. I know that because my Node server receives chunks.

```
let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onload = () => {
    console.log("Done");
};

req.open('POST', location.origin + ':1337');
req.send('test');
```

All good and **normal**.

HOWEVER. The second I change it to this

```
let req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.onload = () => {
    console.log("Done");
};
req.upload.onprogress = (e) => {
    console.log("Progress");
};

req.open('POST', location.origin + ':1337');
req.send('test');
```

, it doesn't send the data anymore.

My Node server isn't special. It's simply an httpServer instance running on :1337, console.log-ing received data chunks.

**What's going on here? Why would the listener disrupt the request?**

Comment: Adding a listener triggers browsers to do a CORS preflight OPTIONS request. So the server must respond to that OPTIONS with a 200 OK success code & the appropriate Access-Control-Allow-\* headers. If the server doesn’t, the preflight fails & the browser stops right there & so never even tries to send the POST request from your code. When you don’t add the event listener, no preflight is performed, so the POST request succeeds— although even then you’ll find you won’t be able to access the response body or response headers unless the response has the appropriate Access-Control-Allow-\* headers.

Comment: @sideshowbarker HOLY HELL THANK YOU SO MUCH. You have some nice knowledge of the exact details of how browsers do this sorta stuff. Guess I learned something new today, very interesting. You saved my day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out adding a listener makes the browser send an OPTIONS request beforehand. I wasn't properly responding to that, now I am.

Thanks @sideshowbarker!

Comment: You could request @sideshowbarker to post the comment as answer